# I can't create a new subscription of tag on instagram

Tags: instagram

I can't create a new subscription of tag on instagram.
When I try to call to post request to create a new subscription, html code will be returned.
Is there anyone who can success to create a new tag subscription on instagram?

Answer (score 0):

Subscriptions for tags was deprecated in Nov. 2015.  Note from [changelog](https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/):

> Deprecation of Realtime subscriptions for tags, locations and geographies